# $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor n - x\right\rfloor = n -1$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

For any integer n and any real number x, if x is not integer then

$$\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor n - x\right\rfloor = n -1$$

How to prove this argument?

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\lfloor n-x\rfloor = n+\lfloor -x\rfloor$ and it should be easy to complete.

Answer (score 3):

Denote $x = i.f$ where $i$ is the integral part of $x$ and $f$ is the fraction part. Because $x$ is not an integer, we know
$
0 < 0.f < 1
$.
Therefore,
$$
\color{blue}{\lfloor x \rfloor} + \color{red}{\lfloor n - x \rfloor} = \color{blue}{\lfloor i.f \rfloor} + \color{red}{\lfloor n - i - 0.f \rfloor} = \color{blue}{i} + \color{red}{n-i-1} = n - 1
$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $x$ is not an integer, there is an integer $m$ such that
$$
m < x < m + 1.
$$
It follows additionally that
$$
n - m - 1 < n - x < n-m.
$$
In conclusion,
$$
\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor n - x \rfloor 
= (m) + (n - m - 1) = n- 1.
$$